# How does a JPA provider access (private) field values when no getter/setter method are defined?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

As entity class field can be mark as `private` when `@Entity` access mode is "**Field**" access , just wanted to understand how provider will able to access entity state in this case as fields are marked as Private and will not be visible outside class ?

**Edit #1 -** As you know , for field access , getter and setter method are optional. So I wanted to understand how provider will access the field when no getter/setter method are provided. Hope this clarify my question .

Comment: not a duplicate . I  have edited my question for clarification .

Comment: Okay, I've removed my flag!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referring to the official [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) (final version, JPA 2.1) in Section 2.2 (page 24) we find:

> The persistent state of an entity is accessed by the persistence provider runtime either via JavaBeans
>   style property accessors (“property access”) or via instance variables (“field access”). Whether persistent
>   properties or persistent fields or a combination of the two is used for the provider’s access to a
>   given class or entity hierarchy is determined as described in Section 2.3, “Access Type”.

In Section 2.3.1 (page 27) this definition is made more concrete - with respect to your question:

> By default, a single access type (field or property access) applies to an entity hierarchy. The default
>   access type of an entity hierarchy is determined by the placement of mapping annotations on the
>   attributes of the entity classes and mapped superclasses of the entity hierarchy that do not explicitly
>   specify an access type. [...]
>
> • When field-based access is used, the object/relational mapping annotations for the entity class
>   annotate the instance variables, and the p*ersistence provider runtime* accesses instance variables
>   **directly**. All non-transient instance variables that are not annotated with the Transient
>   annotation are persistent.
>
> • When property-based access is used, the object/relational mapping annotations for the entity
>   class annotate the getter property accessors, and the persistence provider runtime accesses persistent state via the property accessor methods. All properties not annotated with the `Transient` annotation are persistent.

The term **directly** refers to an access strategy which allows the manipulation of an object's *field* (value) without the need to use getter/setter methods. In Java and for most OR-mappers (at least the ones I know of) this is achieved via [Introspection](http://web.archive.org/web/20090226224821/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html) - using the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). This way, classes' fields can be inspected for and manipulated to hold/represent data values from the (relational) database entries (i.e., their respective columns).

For instance, the provider **Hibernate** gives the following explanation in their [User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html):

> 2.5.9. Access strategies
>
> As a JPA provider, Hibernate can introspect both the entity attributes
>   (instance fields) or the accessors (instance properties). By default,
>   the placement of the @Id annotation gives the default access strategy.

*Important note*:

Be careful when experimenting with different access strategies! The following requirement must hold (JPA specification, p. 28):

> All such classes in the entity hierarchy whose access type is defaulted in this way must be consistent in
>   their placement of annotations on ***either* fields *or* properties**, such that a single, consistent default access
>   type applies within the hierarchy.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The provider can use reflection to access a private field on a class instance.